# Jagged dictionary of dynamic depth?

Tags: c#, recursion, jagged-arrays, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to extract from a series of strings which represents depth like:

```
'foo/bar/x'
'foo/bar/baz/x'
'foo/bar/baz/x'
'foo/bar/lol/x'
```

Where `x` is a number I don't care about. I've got as far as splitting on the `/` and looping through, at which point in PHP I'd do something like check where in the loop I am (using `for (i=0; etc)`) and then use that to determine my depth to build an output array like:

```
output['foo']['bar'] = 1
output['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 2
output['foo']['bar']['lol'] = 1
```

The trouble is the 'depth' is dynamic and might be either just 3/4 deep (which I could just account for with lots of checks on the value of `i` and handling them separately) or say 10 or more deep in which case some kind of recursive function is probably best.

I've come across the issue that to have a string as an array index I need to use a dictionary, but you have to specify the types in the dictionary, meaning you need to know the depth in advanced (correct me if I'm wrong) when instantiating a dictionary object.

I guess an attack might be something like calling a recursive function such that each time it's called you pass `i` to indicate the depth, then the function calls itself decrementing `i` each time until it has built the portion of the tree from that input string but it's what storage structures I use for that in C# that I am not sure about.

The final output will be a CSV that I can open as a spreadsheet to look like:

```
Foo        0
|__Bar     1
   |__Baz  2
   |__Lol  1
```

Perhaps one direction for a solution is to use a pure C# Array and simply store the title (e.g. `foo`) in there, keeping information out of array indicies, which is probably best practice anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Even in PHP, If `output['foo']['bar'] = 1`, how can `output['foo']['bar']['baz']` exist? Either `output['foo']['bar']` is a dictionary, or it is a value. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it isn't a good idea... consider also: `var whatAmI = output['foo']['bar'];`, `whatAmI == 1`? `whatAmI is Dictionary`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own class with following members:

```
class Directory
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Directory> SubDirectories { get; set; }
}
```

Store your data using it and then recursively export it to CSV.

To get `output["foo"]["bar"]` syntax possible implement indexer within your class:

```
public Directory this[string name]
{
    get { return SubDirectories.ContainsKey("name") ? SubDirectories[key] : null; }
    set { SubDirectories.Add(name, value); }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be simpler to implement some kind of Tree data structure.

Comment: It is some kind of Tree, where `SubDirectories` property holds the leaves, isn't it?

Comment: Well the subdirectory has no reference to its parent.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary in that case, but can be easily solved.

Comment: @Romoku - In trees, you do not have to have a pointer to your parent. for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: @Kobi in linked list based tree you don't.

Answer (score 2):

While Marcin Juraszek solution is great, I just want to expand his answer just a little bit with `dynamic` sugar. It's not the fact, that this solution will fit your need, but just consider it as an example. I will make `Directory<T>` generic, so you can use whatever type for `value` (note that due to dynamic nature I have one cast in implementation `(T)value`)

```
class Directory<T> : DynamicObject
{
    private T Value;
    private Dictionary<string, Directory<T>> SubDirectories;

    public Directory()
    {
        SubDirectories = new Dictionary<string, Directory<T>>();
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out Object result)
    {
        if (!SubDirectories.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            SubDirectories[binder.Name] = new Directory<T>();

        result = SubDirectories[binder.Name];   
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, Object value)
    {
        if (!SubDirectories.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            SubDirectories[binder.Name] = new Directory<T>();

        SubDirectories[binder.Name].Value = (T)value;
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And now you can use `dynamic` feature, available from **C# 4.0**

```
dynamic dir = new Directory<string>();

dir.foo = "Foo Value";
dir.foo.bar = "Bar Value";
dir.foo.bar.baz = "baz value";
dir.foo.bar.Lol = "Lol value";

Console.WriteLine(dir.foo.bar.Lol); //will print Lol value
Console.WriteLine(dir.foo.bar.baz); //will print baz value
```

which is:

```
Foo        Foo Value
|__Bar     Bar Value
   |__Baz  baz value
   |__Lol  Lol value
```

you can also override [TryGetIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx) and [TrySetIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetindex.aspx) so that you can pass complex strings, which can't be used as properties in C#

Comment: Using `ToString` is a cheating a bit, isn't it? Also, you cannot have a directory called "Value" or "SubDirectories". Next, we can even go uglier: `public static implicit operator T(Directory<T> m){return m.Value;}` would enable `string s = dir.foo.bar;`. As I've said in the comment - this isn't a good idea...

Comment: @Kobi Good note, you definitely should make inner structure private and then you can `dir.SubDirectories = "Foo Value";`. Also, implicit operator T is not the best idea, but again, dynamic is tricky when integrating with static structures. I use `Value.ToString()` so inner `Value` can have complex logic on `ToString`. Anyway, I've noted that this is just a demo or example, not a production code.